# Ionic HTTP request from PHP service with JSON can not be processed

Tags: php, json, angular, ionic3

I'm trying to build an Angular-Ionic app, which gets information from a central database via http request information. These are built by PHP in the form of JSON. I also get the information back but can not process it.

My JSON looks like this:

```
[
   {0: {id: 1, title: 'TITLE', image:'TITEL'},
   {1: {id: 2, title: 'TITLE', image:'TITEL'},
   {2: {id: 3, title: 'TITLE', image:'TITEL'}
]
```

This is my PHP-Code:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
   header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}
// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 
    {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
 }
$mysqli = new mysqli("[DATABASE_URL]", "[DATABASE_USER]", "[DATABASE_PWD]", "[DATABASE]");
$query = "SELECT id, title, image FROM database ORDER BY title ASC";
$dbresult = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $dbresult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $data[] = array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'title' => $row['title'],
        'image' => $row['image']
    );
}

if($dbresult){
    $result = json_encode(utf8ize($data),JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
} else {
    $result = "{success:false}";
}
echo $result;


function utf8ize($d) {
    if (is_array($d)) {
        foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
            $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($d)) {
        return utf8_encode($d);
    }
    return $d;
 }
```

I would like to build a list with the obtained data in Angular / Ionic. I use Ionic 3 on the latest version. Http and HttpClient, as well as HttpProvider did not bring any result:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of newsData">
  <img src="../../assets/imgs/{{ item.image }}.jpeg"/>
  <div class="card-title">{{ item.title }}</div>
  <div class="card-subtitle">{{item.id}} Rezepte</div> 
</ion-card>
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the response from your http request to a variable and than just do it the way you did.

If you give more informations about what you did in ionic to get the response we can see what's the mistake here.

Comment: I would like to pick up a list of cooking recipes from the server and list them. But I can not handle the answers. I need the right construct to get the data right. Can you give me an ideal code snippet, which deposits a request under Ionic 3. Which is called by PHP. What information do you need?

Comment: show us your rest provider and where does newsData come from

Comment: import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-kategorien',
  templateUrl: 'kategorien.html'
})
export class KategorienPage {
    newsData: Observable<any>;

    constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) {
        this.getdata();
    }

    getdata(){
        this.newsData = this.httpClient.get('CALLED_PHP.php'};
}

Comment: ^ @Last Message: I have changed the method like following link: https://ionicacademy.com/http-calls-ionic/

Comment: Here's my response, how do I handle those in Ionic now? {"count":9,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"0":{"id":"8","kategorie":"Auftriche und So\u00dfen","bild":"aufstriche_und_sossen","title":"Auftriche und So\u00dfen","image":"aufstriche_und_sossen"},"1":{"id":"9","kategorie":"Beilagen und Salate","bild":"beilagen_und_salate","title":"Beilagen und Salate","image":"beilagen_und_salate"},"2":{"id":"2","kategorie":"Brot","bild":"brot","title":"Brot","image":"brot"},...}]}

Comment: I found my problem. It was when creating the JSON, the square brackets.